# to change only the table color using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

im new to javascript.. im trying to create a page where when the user selects the colors the particular color should change but only the `<table>` and its `<td>` color should get changed on **Click function** any anyone pls help me in dis.. thanks in advance.

Comment: A comment like this makes me wish we could vote comments down. If you were helping someone learn computers, @DanSingerman, you'll probably tell him "google 'Start button'".

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
 document.getElementById("table_id_here").style.backgroundColor = "#00ff00";
```